# Error in SQL syntax on import of database

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to import a database from my xamppserver (v3.2.2) to my webserver at one.com. I exported it from phpmyadmin using sql (I tried csv and got the same error) and get this message:

```
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 15
STR: ><
SQL: <!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='sv' dir='ltr' class='firefox firefox53'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><style id="cfs-style">html{display: none;


SQL query:

<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='sv' dir='ltr' class='firefox firefox53'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" /><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"><style id="cfs-style">html{display: none;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='sv' dir='ltr' class='firefox firefox53'><head><meta c' at line 1
```

When I open the file, line 1 is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='sv' dir='ltr' class='firefox firefox53'><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

I'm using a MariaDB server.

Any ideas what's causing this problem?

Comment: Your export is somehow wrong. It looks like a HTML page instead of an export in SQL or csv format. How did you save the export to your disk? Seems like you save the HTML page instead of the source.

Comment: I had the same thought, but I'm not experienced wih databases. I exported the database from phpmyadmin and saved it as a .sql file. I have another go with the export, thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried to make another export and when I include all tables it opens as a .htm file and want to open it with a webbrowser. If I exclude all tables and export it it opens as .sql file, here is the content: -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Värd: 127.0.0.1
-- Tid vid skapande: 06 jun 2017 kl 20:38
-- Serverversion: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- PHP-version: 7.1.1

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

Comment: Apperently there is a limit in phpmyadmin at 300 lines, I added this line in php.ini,  max_input_vars = 5000 inside, and now it exports correctly.